# How to sum all the values of a list that is inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to sum all of the values that are inside of this list while still keeping their position:

```
{'swimming': ['1000', '1200'], 'fencing': ['200', '100'], 'athletics': ['600']}
```

after the addition the output should look like:

```
{'swimming': ['2200'], 'fencing': ['300'], 'athletics': ['600']}
```

I have tried a few examples, however, they require the name of the list. How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Access the `'swimming'` key, convert all `string` objects into `int` objects and sum it.

Comment: Add more description of what you want to do, along with the codes you say you've tried.

Comment: Nothing requires "the name of" the list - what is required is the list object itself. Read this for more on "names" in Python: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
>>> d = {'swimming': ['1000', '1200']}
>>> l = map(int, d['swimming'])
>>> sum(l)
2200
```

Loop through the dictionary for its each key, if the value consists more than one item in the list then map each of them into integer format, sum them, type cast into string format and put into a list else for only one item in the list leave it as it is. For changing the whole dictionary, try this :

```
>>> d = {'swimming': ['1000', '1200'], 'fencing': ['200', '100'], 'athletics': ['600']}
>>> for k in d:
...   s = [str(sum(map(int, d[k])))] if len(d[k])>1 else d[k]
...   d[k] = s
...
>>> d
{'swimming': ['2200'], 'fencing': ['300'], 'athletics': ['600']}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use loop:

```
d = {'swimming': ['1000', '1200']}
sumOfList =sum (int(n) for n in d['swimming'])
```

Comment: A mere generator expression would be enough (`sum()` works on any iterable): `sum(int(n) for n in xxx)`

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {'swimming': ['1000', '1200']}
print(sum(map(int, dictionary['swimming'])))
2200 # Output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {'swimming': ['1000', '1200']}
for each_list in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[each_list] = sum(list(map(int, my_dict[each_list])))
```

1. loop your dictionary by keys
2. transform datatype within the list from string to int so that they can be summed up: list(map(int, my_dict[each_list]))
3. sum list

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this solution:

```
d = {'swimming': ['1000', '1200'], 'fencing': ['200', '100'], 'athletics': ['600']}
for (k, v) in d.items():
    ints_v = map(int, v)
    d[k] = str(sum(ints_v))
print(d)
```